# Scroll bar issue in position: absolute;

Tags: css, jsx, tailwind-css

There is a sort of scroll bar in the h4::after section, as shown in the image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nawZW.png)

this is my jsx code :

```
<ul className="flex space-x-4 py-10 pl-3 mx-auto text-left steps-ul p-3 pt-50 grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-3">
    <li className="col">
            <span className="step-number">1</span>
                <h4 className="text-white"></h4>
                <p></p>
            <div className="right-arrow"> 
                <img src={RightArrow} alt="Right arrow"></img>
            </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and this my css code :

```
.steps-ul {
    list-style: none;
    gap: 100px;
}

.steps-ul li {
    position: relative;
    background: url(../../asset/img/small-shape.svg) no-repeat;
}

.col {
    flex: 1 0 0%;
}

.step-number {
    color: #ffc629;
    font-size: 96px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.steps-ul h4 {
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.steps-ul h4::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    left: 0;
    bottom: -15px;
    background: #ffc629;
    height: 4px;
    width: 90px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

where is my mistake?t

i want to make it, exactly like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMFK0.png)

Comment: Why do you have <ul> opening tags at the end?

Comment: I suspect that all you need to do is remove `overflow-x: auto` from `.steps-ul h4 { }`

Answer (score 0):

My question is, I have found a solution.

it remains only to add this :

```
    .steps-ul .col {
       overflow: visible;
     }
```